# Possibility to use the greater then operator in a switch statement

Tags: php, switch-statement

Below you can see my code. It outputs the 'The number is hundred'. It works perfectly.

```
$var = 100;

switch($var){
    case (100):
        echo 'The number is hundred';
        break;
    default:
        echo 'default';
        break;
}

//Output:
The number is hundred
```

I just wanting to know this for the purpose of understanding if it's possible to do something like this:

```
case (greather then 100):
case (> 100):
```

And could you also explain why it's not possible or is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but it's not considered a good coding practise as `switchs` should only do equality evaluations.

To do it use this syntax:

```
switch (TRUE) {
    case ($var == 100): echo 'The number is one hundred';
    case ($var > 100): echo 'The number is greater than one hundred';
    echo 'default';
}
```

[Source](http://data.agaric.com/how-use-less-or-greater-switch-statement)